# Regarding Dropdown To get the selected item as selected when a button is clicked

Tags: php, html, css, database

I have a form named reg.php and its action is reg.php , i want the selected dropdown value when clicked on submit to remain selected , what i have done so far is given below

I have checked the questions that are posted but i couldnt match it with my code

```
<?php
if( $_POST['registerbtn']){
$selected_value = $_POST['selectID'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  linecard_name FROM selection WHERE select_id = '$selected_value'");
$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
$linecard_name= $rows['linecard_name'];
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection " . "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
if(  $rownw['linecard_name'] == $linecard_name)  {
$options = "<option  selected =selected  value=".$rownw['select_id']."> " .$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
}
}
}

require("./connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT select_id, linecard_name FROM selection ". "ORDER BY linecard_name";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
$options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
} 
mysql_close() ;

$form = "<form action='./reg.php'  method='post'> 
<table>
<tr>
<td>  </td>
<td>  <font color='red'> $errormsg </font> </td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td> Select  Linecard </td> 
<td> <Select name='selectID' >  <option value = '0'>  Select  from here </option> $options  </select></td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td  > <input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value='Register' />   </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
echo $form;
```

The select statements before the register button is clicked is for filling the dropdown from the database,
I just want the selected items to remain selected when the particular selection is done by the user and register button is clicked ,
in which case my code fills the dropdown again but now with the user selected item as selected but without clearing the previous items filled in the dropdown i.e before the register button is clicked,
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it's cleanest to do it with a variable, like this:

```
while($rownw = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
  $selected = '';
  if ($rownw['select_id'] == $selected_value){
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
  }
  $options .= "<option value = ".$rownw['select_id']." $selected > ".$rownw['linecard_name']. " </option> ";
}
```

Comment: i just need how to get only the selected value in the dropdown without filling the dropdown again

Comment: Can you tell as how to refresh the dropdown after the mail has been sent ? @Chris